# OSX Wine program not recognizing USB device

Tags: macos, usb, wine

I'm trying to use CSR BlueFlash to dump the firmware/upload new firmware to a JBL Flip 3 speaker. I've put the speaker into DFU mode and it shows up in the OSX ioregistry (see below):

[image]

but when I try to run BlueFlash, no USB devices are found. Looking in `~/.wine/dosdevices`, there are no `COM<number>` symlinks. In fact, I don't believe there are any `/dev/tty` devices corresponding to the USB device. I've tried many different USB port numbers (like `idProduct` and `bcdDevice`) but BlueFlash finds no USB devices with that number.

I have seen a project where someone got BlueFlash to recognize the device with a JBL Flip 4 so I am fairly certain that what I am trying to do is possible.

Does anyone know how to get Wine on OSX to recognize a USB device?